Local maximum is global maximum of $f(x) = \dfrac{x}{x^2+a^2}$
Consider the function $f(x) = \dfrac{x}{x^2+a^2}$ where $a$ is a real constant.
a) Find the value of $a$ such that $f$ has a local maximum at $x=3$ and a local minimum at $x=-3$
b) Show that the local maximum is also a global maximum and the local minimum is also a global minimum in the natural domain of $f(x)$
Hint : Calculate $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} f(x)}$ and draw a sketch of the function.
I have tried using the second derivative test:
Since $f'(x) = \dfrac{a^2-x^2}{(a^2+x^2)^2}$, so $f'(x) = 0$ occurs when $x=a$ and $x=-a$. Then, after evaluating the second derivative value of $f$, which is $f''(x) = \dfrac{8x^3}{(a^2+x^2)^3} - \dfrac{6x}{(a^2+x^2)^2}$. Since $f$ has local max at $x=3$, then $f''(3) < 0$ and since $f$ has local min at $x=-3$, then $f''(-3)>0$. I am confused which one is the value of $a$, is it $3$, or $-3$, or both?

What have you tried ?

i have used the second derivative test, but the result of the second derivative is quite bad

Please then edit to include your effort in the post so that others can help

I have added them

Both $a=3$ and $a=-3$ are valid. Note that the function $f$ is the same in either case. You may want to check if the exercise contains the assumption $a>0$.

A completely different approach is to study the values $m\in{\mathbb R}$ for which the equation $f(x)=m$ has a solution. It is very simple here.

I haven't worked out the details, but I think the first derivative test (using a sign chart) will be much more informative and simpler to apply than the second derivative test, especially for global extrema.

thanks for the help
